# Checking if two objects added equals

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Hi I have just started learning javascript and are a bit unsure about syntax.
I am doing the bowling Kata and are checking to see if a spare should be awarded.
Here is my jasmine test and my attempt at the syntax. Test:

```
 it('can check for a spare', function() {
     var game = new Game();
     game.roll(7);
     game.roll(3);
     expect(game.rolls[2]).toEqual(10);
     expect(game.isSpare()).toBe(true)
 });
```

Prototype:

```
Game.prototype.isSpare = function() {
    if (self.roll + self.roll) === 10
}
return true;
};
```

Sorry if this a bit of a noob question, but can't seem to find the answer anywhere.
Thak you

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question, there should be a `rolls` property, and each `roll` function call should add to it. And `isSpare` should just check if `rolls` property is equal to 10.

Something like this;

```
Game = function() {
  this.rolls = 0;
}
Game.prototype.roll = function(num) {
  this.rolls += num;
};
Game.prototype.isSpare = function () {
    if(this.rolls === 10) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

You can also shorten isSpare function like this;

```
Game.prototype.isSpare = function () {
    return (this.rolls === 10);
};
```